# Handlebars Reference two separate objects in the same line

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a lookup object called `Locations`:

```
{
  'CA:' 'California',
  'NV': 'Nevada',
  'FL': 'Florida',
  ...
}
```

and an array of addresses:

```
[
  {street:'123 place', state:'FL', ...}
]
```

Is it possible to reference the output of a lookup in a handlebars template tag?

Something like this is what I've tried

```
{{#each addresses}}
  {{Lookup[this.state]}}
{{/each}}
```

But I get an error. So i'm probably referencing Lookup wrong.

Comment: The example in [the docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) says `{{lookup ../foo @index}}`, which, in addition to being lowercase (`lookup`), takes two arguments separated by spaces, not a single argument surrounded by square brackets.

Comment: ok. that ended up being the answer. would you like to add an answer? or shall I?

Comment: Great! I've added an answer with a working snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`lookup`](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) helper, in addition to being lower-case (not "`Lookup`"), takes two arguments separated by spaces. The first argument is the path to the object (or array) you want to do the lookup in and the second argument is the key to use. So in your case you probably want `{{lookup ../locations this.state}}`. Here it is in a snippet:

```js
var source =
  '{{#each addresses}}' +
    '<li>{{lookup ../locations this.state}}</li>' +
  '{{/each}}';

var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var data = {
  locations: {
    'CA': 'California',
    'NV': 'Nevada',
    'FL': 'Florida',
    // ...
  },
  addresses: [
    { street: '123 Place', state: 'FL' },
    { street: '456 Other', state: 'NV' },
    { street: '789 Last', state: 'CA' },
    // ...
  ]
};

document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = template(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.4/handlebars.js"></script>
<ul id="list"/>
```